I turned off crowd control and dialed down the spam filter on a subreddit I moderate. But why is Reddit still automatically removing my posts?
I signed up on Reddit but never posted anything. Then I created a new subreddit. I am its lone moderator. I winded down the spam filter, and turned off crowd control for posts as low as possible. See screenshots:

But after I submitted a post (NOT a comment) on my own subreddit, Reddit still auto filtered and removed my post! Why? What more must I do?


It seems you’ve encountered Reddit’s automated spam filter, which automatically filters links from certain domains, despite any subreddit settings.
There are two categories of these restricted links:

Mod-overrideable links: These are links that, although initially filtered by the Reddit spam filter, can be approved by a moderator. You can also configure AutoModerator to automatically approve these links, and they will then be displayed in the subreddit feed as normal.

Non-mod-overrideable links: These are links that even moderators cannot approve. Even if you attempt to approve them, they will be re-filtered by Reddit’s spam filter.
A quick way to identify if your link falls into this category is to approve the post in your mod queue. If it reappears in the queue after approval, then posts with links to that domain are not permitted on Reddit. Your only option as a moderator is to remove them.
What I do with posts or comments containing these types of links is set AutoModerator to automatically remove them. Then, I have AutoModerator leave a comment explaining that posts or comments with links to that domain are blocked by Reddit’s filters. For comments, I suggest a workaround like changing https://example.com to example (dot) com.


It might take some experimenting to get it right, but this approach should help you figure out which links are causing trouble and how to handle them.
